# Is it possible to run SQL query directly on class tbl_sql (or tbl_dbi)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble, rsqlite, dbplyr

Example code:

```
library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)

# will require more details (like user, password, host, port, etc.)
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
data(USArrests)
dbWriteTable(con, "USArrests", USArrests)
dbListTables(con)

d0 <- tbl(con, "USArrests")
dbGetQuery(d0, "select * from USArrests")
dbGetQuery(d0, "select * from d0")
```

Which returns:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetQuery’ for signature ‘"tbl_dbi", "character"’
```

Obviously I could just use dbGetQuery on con, but was wondering if there is a way to have it work on d0 directly.

Thanks.

Comment: Not `tbl_sql` or `tbl_dbi` but the sqldf package can process data frames using SQL and a variety of backends including sqlite.  `library(sqldf); sqldf("select * from USArrests limit 3")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, looking at the `str` helped reveal how to access the needed elements using the following commands:

```
  con <- d0$src$con
  db_name <- db_list_tables(con)[1]
```

Comment: This looks interesting. Could you explain what it is doing?

Comment: Hi Rasmus, it is getting the original connection and used database name from the dbplyr object (tbl_lazy, tbl_sql). This way we could directly use things like dbGetQuery on it without first going through the dplyr collect function. I personally wanted it for getting a sample of the rows - but it makes sense only if no other dplyr verbs have been used on the object.

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand, is the `tbl()` function which is a SQL statement of type `SELECT * FROM Table` this works over DBMS and to retrieve data from database server it need a pull function like `collect()`. On the other hand, is the function `dbGetQuery()` which retrieves the data into R session using a SQL query. Both requires a connection to server and a statement, but the first create the statement using SQL translations and the other is the user which write the SQL query.

To illustrate I will use a temporal table `tmp` in a postgreSQL DBMS:

```
# Example on postgreSQL
library(tidyverse)
library(dbplyr)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(DBI) # This is loaded with RPostgreSQL package

con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), 
                 dbname="test",
                 host="localhost",
                 port=5432,
                 user="user",
                 password="pass")
```

Dummy data to PostgreSQL server

```
date <- data_frame(Col1 = c("20180212", "20180213"),
                   Col2 = c("A", "B"))
dbWriteTable(con, "tmp", date, temporary = TRUE)
```

With `tbl()` function

```
tbl(con, "tmp") %>% show_query()

#><SQL> 
#>SELECT * 
#>FROM "tmp"

tbl(con, "tmp") %>% 
  mutate(date = to_date(Col1, "YYYYMMDD")) %>%
  show_query()

#><SQL>
#>SELECT "row.names", "Col1", "Col2", TO_DATE("Col1", 'YYYYMMDD') AS "date"
#>FROM "tmp"

tbl(con, "tmp") %>% 
  mutate(date = to_date(Col1, "YYYYMMDD")) %>% #this works on DBMS
  collect() %>% #This retrive to R session
  str()

#>Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#> $ row.names: chr  "1" "2"
#> $ Col1     : chr  "20180212" "20180213"
#> $ Col2     : chr  "A" "B"
#> $ date     : Date, format: "2018-02-12" "2018-02-13"
```

With `dbGetQuery()` function

```
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM tmp") %>% 
  str()

#>'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#> $ row.names: chr  "1" "2"
#> $ Col1     : chr  "20180212" "20180213"
#> $ Col2     : chr  "A" "B"

dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM tmp") %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(Col1, format = "%Y%m%d")) %>% #This works on R session
  str()

#>'data.frame': 2 obs. of  4 variables:
#> $ row.names: chr  "1" "2"
#> $ Col1     : chr  "20180212" "20180213"
#> $ Col2     : chr  "A" "B"
#> $ date     : Date, format: "2018-02-12" "2018-02-13"
```

Conclusion

`tbl()` function is a high level over `dbGetQuery()` in R-programming. Consider to re-design your code chain understanding the differences between both functions and best uses for these.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use `dbGetQuery` with `dplyr` in this way, it only work with `DBIConnection`.

Also, your first query is redundany, `d0` already represent the `USArrests` data and second query is nonsense.

`dplyr` is using a bit different approach, it uses `dplyr` verbs and creating an SQL query:

```
d0 %>% filter(Murder > 10) %>% show_query()
```

Comment: Hi @m0nhawk. I know that it doesn't work, the question is how can I write something like "filter". It obviously runs some SQL, I want to be able to write a customized function that does it as well.

Comment: @TalGalili I don't understand what you want. You want to write your own `filter`? Then you can check the `dplyr` development guides.